# UINavigationController back and close button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a navigation controller. The controller works well and shows me the back button for go back to the window. But when I add this code for add the close button:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Chiudi" 
                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self
                       action:@selector(dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:)];          
  
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton;
  
  [doneButton release];

}
```

...then the back button disappears, and I can only see the close button. Why?

Comment: you mean you push a navigation controller?

Comment: What do you mean by adding some code? Are you overlapping your 'Close' button on top of your 'Back' button?

Comment: Hello, i used to have this same problem, then i moved the creation of this new button in viewDidAppear:, please try and let me know

Comment: yes pushing the back button disappear

Comment: and adding some code means:   adding the code i posted in the question

Comment: OK SOLVED THE PROBLEM IS dismissModalViewControllerAnimated I HAD TO USE     [self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THE PROBLEM was in

```
 dismissModalViewControllerAnimated
```

I HAD TO USE

```
 [self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];     
 [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```